# Clean up a column in python

Tags: python, regex, data-cleaning

I have a column that looks like something like this:

```
2014 Estimate
<td>1,968</td>
<td>185</td>
<td>845</td>
<td>439</td>
<td>107</td>
<td>2,735</td>
<td>1,312</td>
<td>1,285<sup id="cite_ref-4" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-4">[4]</a></sup></td>
```

there is some cleaning to do, the output should look like something like this:

```
2014 Estimamte
    1968
    185
    845
    439107
    2735
    1312
    1285
```

I guess that the solution could look like an iteration through the row that apply a regex formula to it? I'm just not quite sure how to go about it, any tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: to give some contest 2014 Estimate is a column in a data frame, I need to clean up the entire column

Comment: What do you mean by cleaning up the entire column? Does it mean not only removing <td> tags but replacing them with whitespaces, or just aligning the data to "Estimate" column?

Comment: extract the numeric values in between > and <

Answer (score 1):

Using BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = """
2014 Estimate
<td>1,968</td>
<td>185</td>
<td>845</td>
<td>439</td>
<td>107</td>
<td>2,735</td>
<td>1,312</td>
<td>1,285<sup id="cite_ref-4" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-4">[4]</a></sup></td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
# Remove [4] in the example
[a.extract() for a in soup("a")]
# Remove commas in numbers
[td.replace_with(td.text.replace(",", "")) for td in soup("td")]

print(soup.text)
```

#### Output

```
2014 Estimate
1968
185
845
439
107
2735
1312
1285
```

Comment: this looks like an interesting approach but it's not working. 2014 Estimate is a column in a data frame

Answer (score 0):

Remove anything in angle brackets and square brackets as well as commas.

```
import re
data = '''2014 Estimate
<td>1,968</td>
<td>185</td>
<td>845</td>
<td>439</td>
<td>107</td>
<td>2,735</td>
<td>1,312</td>
<td>1,285<sup id="cite_ref-4" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-4">[4]</a></sup></td>'''
print(re.sub(r'<.*?>|\[.*?\]|,', '', data, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

This outputs:

```
2014 Estimate
1968
185
845
439
107
2735
1312
1285
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! could you break it down to me? 
in order to assign the output values as new values of the column,
could I do data['Estimate 2014'] = re.sub(r'[\[<].*?[\]>]|,', '', data, flags=re.DOTALL) ?

Comment: The regex `<.*?>|\[.*?\]|,` uses the or operator `|` to combine three patterns in one. The first pattern `<.*?>` looks for anything in angle brackets. The second pattern `\[.*?\]` looks for anything in square brackets. The third pattern `,`, well, matches just a comma. `re.sub` then uses this combined pattern to substitute any matching string with an empty string, effectively removing everything you want to clean up. Added the `re.DOTALL` flag to let `.` match a newline just in case some of the HTML tags spans over multiple lines.